# How to link to a function 'as is' in another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to link to another spreadsheet like this:

```
=template!G2
```

but G2 it self has:

```
=SUM(B2:F2)/5
```

How would I link to the content of G2 at template spreadsheet while still evaluating the function 'as is' inside the local cells for the referencing spreadsheet?

**EDIT**

I want to feed the function in the cell of template ex: `=SUM(B2:F2)/5` from the cells at the spreadsheet, but what I get is that the source of the `B2:F2` is linked to the template it self rather than the referencing spreadsheet, so how to use the referencing spreadsheet as the source for `B2:F2` ?

Comment: You could post a sheet to explain your problem and the desired result.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, you are trying to reference to a formula from a different sheet, but you want it to use range from current sheet?  I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, as English is not my native language, I would appreciate it if you can edit the topic of this question to make it better

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display both the output of the formula and the contents of template!G2 in the same cell?  If so, you could try something like:

`=SUM(B2:F2)/5&" ("&template!G2&")"`